# How can i add a Bi-LSTM layer on top of bert model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I'm using **pytorch** and I'm using the base **pretrained bert** to classify sentences for hate speech.
I want to implement a **Bi-LSTM** layer that takes as an input all outputs of the latest
transformer encoder from the bert model as a new model (class that implements **nn.Module**), and i got confused with the **nn.LSTM** parameters.
I tokenized the data using

```py
bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=int(data['class'].nunique()),output_attentions=False,output_hidden_states=False)
```

My data-set has 2 columns: class(label), sentence.
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:
Also, after processing the input in the bi-lstm, the network sends the  final hidden state to a fully connected network that performs classication using the softmax activation function. how can I do that ?

Comment: Can you share your attempts?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it as follows:

```
from transformers import BertModel
class CustomBERTModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
          super(CustomBERTModel, self).__init__()
          self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
          ### New layers:
          self.lstm = nn.LSTM(768, 256, batch_first=True,bidirectional=True)
          self.linear = nn.Linear(256*2, <number_of_classes>)
          

    def forward(self, ids, mask):
          sequence_output, pooled_output = self.bert(
               ids, 
               attention_mask=mask)

          # sequence_output has the following shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, 768)
          lstm_output, (h,c) = self.lstm(sequence_output) ## extract the 1st token's embeddings
          hidden = torch.cat((lstm_output[:,-1, :256],lstm_output[:,0, 256:]),dim=-1)
          linear_output = self.linear(hidden.view(-1,256*2)) ### assuming that you are only using the output of the last LSTM cell to perform classification

          return linear_output

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = CustomBERTModel()
```

Comment: I have a few questions: (1). how is this a Bi-LSTM layer? (2). how and where you are taking all outputs of the latest transformer encoder from the bert model ?

Comment: I had initially given the answer for LSTM. I have updated the answer according to Bi-LSTM

Comment: Answer for 2: I have already added the comments on `sequence_output` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, so the output that has all the outputs of the last transformer encoders will be in sequence_output ? also i have another question, where do I specify the number of classes ? because I'm trying to classify the sentences into 3 labels, and I saw examples that they do `BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels = 2)` or you don't have to do it because you add the number of labels in nn.Linear ? also, why the input for nn.Linear is 256*2 ? @Ashwin Geet D'Sa

Comment: `self.linear = nn.Linear(256*2, <number_of_classes>, batch_first=True)`; specify the number of classes there.

Comment: Thank you, and last question,
you said in a comment in the code : "assuming that you are only using the output of the last LSTM cell to perform classification", what i want is after processing the input in the bi-lstm, the network sends the final hidden state to a fully connected network that performs classication using the softmax activation function. how can i do that ? @Ashwin Geet D'Sa

Comment: Isn't the code already doing the operation of FC layer? You just have to add softmax after linear.  Moreover, this is not a place to ask sequential questions. That's why the quidelines asks to mention what you have tried in the question itself, which you haven't.