# How to add LSTM layer on top of Huggingface BERT model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am working on a binary classification task and would like to try adding lstm layer on top of the last hidden layer of huggingface BERT model, however, I couldn't reach the last hidden layer. Is it possible to combine BERT with LSTM?

```py
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
tain_inputs, train_labels, train_masks = data_prepare_BERT(
    train_file, lab2ind, tokenizer, content_col, label_col, 
    max_seq_length)
validation_inputs, validation_labels, validation_masks = data_prepare_BERT(
    dev_file, lab2ind, tokenizer, content_col, label_col,max_seq_length)

# Load BertForSequenceClassification, the pretrained BERT model with a single linear classification layer on top.
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_path, num_labels=len(lab2ind))
```

Comment: You need to provide more code and details.

Comment: @Ruli I have just edited it!

Comment: There is an available answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205582/how-can-i-add-a-bi-lstm-layer-on-top-of-bert-model/65217371#65217371

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, thank you! I have already tried it, but I got this error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_first'` for nn.Linear()!

Comment: The `batch_first` is only for LSTM, and not for Linear. So, do check your code again.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is possible, but you need to implement it yourself. [`BertForSequenceClassification`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1449) class is a wrapper for `BertModel`. It runs the model, takes the hidden state corresponding to the `[CLS]` tokens, and applies a classifier on top of that.

In your case, you can the class as a starting point, and add there an LSTM layer between the BertModel and the classifier. The BertModel returns both the hidden states and a pooled state for classification in a tuple. Just take the other tuple member than is used in the original class.

Although it is technically possible, I would expect any performance gain compared to using `BertForSequenceClassification`. Finetuning of the Transformer layers can learn anything that an additional LSTM layer is capable of.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Dose adding LSTM to the [BertForSequenceClassification](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1449) class required additional computational cost (I'm using colab GPU)? I mean if I add it to the original class, would I need to re-train the whole model?

Comment: Also, I would like to try adding BiLSTM and CNN-LSTM. Do you think this will improve performance?

Comment: What do you mean re-train the whole model? The Bert model is pre-trained, you can fine-tune it or not. Anything you add on top of Bert needs to be trained from scratch, no matter if it is a simple classifier or LSTM.

Comment: Ad other architectures: it is possible that your particular problem is very well suited for LSTM or CNN and you would get significantly better performance, but I would not expect much compared to fine-tuning BERT.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you so much, @Jindřich. I thought if I would add an additional layer on top of the last hidden layer in BERT there is a way to get the hidden states of this layer and enter them to a new layer without train BERT from scratch.