# Query regarding Pytorch LSTM code snippet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

In the Stack Overflow thread [How can i add a Bi-LSTM layer on top of bert model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205582/how-can-i-add-a-bi-lstm-layer-on-top-of-bert-model), there is a line of code:

```
hidden = torch.cat((lstm_output[:,-1, :256],lstm_output[:,0, 256:]),dim=-1)
```

Can someone explain why the concatenation of last and first tokens and not any other? What would these two tokens contain that they were chosen?

Comment: OP is trying to do sequence classification using BERT. The first token of the generated sequence should be the 'CLS' token, which is used for classification (see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66207/what-is-purpose-of-the-cls-token-and-why-is-its-encoding-output-important). Because the model is bidirectional, I think they are trying to get the "first" token in both directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bidirectional models, hidden states gets concatenated at each step; so, the line basically concatenates the first `:256` units of the last hidden state in the positive direction (`-1`) to the last `256:` units of the last hidden state in the negative direction (`0`). Such locations contain the most "interesting" *summary* of the input sequence.

I've written [a longer and detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683970/7347631) on how hidden states are constructed in PyTorch for recurrent modules.